# Laravel 3rd level relationship

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent-relationship

I have a Post model and Post model can have many Categories, also Category has many SubCategories.
So the use can assign only Categories under a Post, also if the want they can assign SubCategories based on the Categories they already selected.

What should be my database setup?

Right now what I am thinking is.

posts

categories

subCategories

post_category // saves the categories for each post

post_subcategory // saves the subCategories for each post

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you may create only one Category table which includes id and parent_id, and in the Category model;

- Create a method that is about having subCategories with hasMany(),
- And then also, create a method that has parentCategories with belongsTo().
  So that you may call each of them from your controllers by using these methods.
  Hope that this will help you to handle your problem.